# C++: Exposing pointers to class with managed memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, scope

I have the following setup:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}

    vector<BigObject*> mPointers;
};
class Bar {
public:
    Foo *exposeSomeFoo() { return &mFoos[42]; }
private:
    vector<Foo> mFoos;
    vector<BigObject> mMemoryManaged;
};
```

I'm basically trying to make sure that at no point in my code will someone accidentally use a `Foo` for which the `Bar` it was exposed from has gone out of scope.

But this is obviously problematic. If I expose pointers to `Foo` like above, they become invalid once `Bar` goes out of scope. If I instead use `Foo exposeSomeFoo()`, the `mPointers` will become invalid once `Bar` goes out of scope, too - and returning copies seems like a bad idea if `mPointers` has a lot of elements!

I've tried solving this by making a private copy constructor:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}

    vector<BigObject*> mPointers;
private:
    Foo(const Foo&);
};
```

But then I get errors when I try to insert a `Foo` into `mFoos` from within `Bar`.

There must be a paradigm that allows full memory safety while still allowing me to expose functionality like this. How can I expose, to code elsewhere, a composite object from `Bar` whose memory is managed specifically by `Bar` or at least in the compilation unit itself?

Comment: Vector of shared_ptr can be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I ended up doing something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(shared_ptr<vector<BigObject> > bigObjects) : mBigObjects(bigObjects) {

    }
private:
    vector<BigObject*> mPointers;
    shared_ptr<vector<BigObject> > mBigObjects;
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {
        mBigObjects = shared_ptr<vector<BigObject> >(new vector<BigObject>);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            mBigObjects->push_back(BigObject());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            mFoos.push_back(Foo(mBigObjects));
    }
    Foo exposeSomeFoo() { return mFoos[42]; }
private:
    shared_ptr<vector<BigObject> > mBigObjects;
    vector<Foo> mFoos;
};
```

I think this is the behavior I want: only when all instances of both `Foo` and `Bar` are destroyed, is the vector with BigObjects actually destroyed. Can someone double-check that this is safe and good practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that all of your objects can *share* resources, such that the resource is alive as long as all of the objects are, just use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) everywhere:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}

    vector<shared_ptr<BigObject>> mPointers;
};

class Bar {
public:
    shared_ptr<Foo> exposeSomeFoo() { return mFoos[42]; }
private:
    vector<shared_ptr<Foo>> mFoos;
    vector<shared_ptr<BigObject>> mMemoryManaged;
};
```

That way, a caller can hold onto `bar.exposeSomeFoo()` without worry - the caller now shares ownsership of it, sot his will be perfectly safe.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! One question. Supposing the client is defining `void function(Bar &bar) { ... }`. Of course the client is 100% sure Bar still exists. Is it bad practice to "collapse" the `shared_ptr` into a simple `Foo*` inside this definition, and how would it be done in that case?

Comment: @bombax Why? Just use the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I'm just concerned about modularity (I have a feeling many programmers do this with a typedef or something?)